# Opening USB communication

Tags: c, eclipse, windows, usb, createfile

I'm trying to communicate with a device through a USB cable:

```
tmp_devid->device_handle = CreateFile(tmp_devid->device_path,
                                      GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                                      FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
                                      NULL,
                                      OPEN_EXISTING,
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
                                      NULL);
```

which returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. `GetLastError()` returns 5 (access denied).

The value of `tmp_devid->device_path` is:

```
path \\?\usb#vid_1fd0&pid_0001#6&944c330&0&2#{98e8484f-e727-43be-8485-4c0968976320}
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the program with elevated privileges.

Comment: I have tried runnng the Eclipse in with "run as administrator", but was of no use.